# MongoId Embedded Document With Reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid3

I have the following case where I have a document that I need to embed in some documents, but for traceability (e.g need to know the amount of people who is subscribed to each type) I need it to be stored as a different document. So when I try to save a default set of Types it says:

`Mongoid::Errors::NoParent: 
Problem:
  Cannot persist embedded document Type without a parent document.`

I don't know how to do it or how to handle this situation, any help or suggestion is appreciated.

```
class Type
  include Mongoid::Document
    embedded_in :typeable, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :client
    field :count, type: Integer # number of people interested in each Type
end

class Client
  include Mongoid::Document
    has_many :types
    embeds_many :discounts, as: :discountable
end

class Discount
  include Mongoid::Document
    embeds_many :types, as: :typeable
    embedded_in :discountable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you can't create standalone documents for an embedded model (you are architecturally preventing that by choosing to embed). If you need to have a standalone set of Types you should use `has_many` and `belongs_to` instead of `embeds_many` and `embedded_in`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about inheritance?

Make your `Client` and `Discount` models inherit from `Type`.
They will benefit from your `Type` fields and you will be able to have a standalone `Type` index too.